# Weapon jitter when playing FPS animation

Tags: unity, 3d, animation, first-person-shooter

I extracted drg's auto cannon, and the gun and arms are separated models.

When I try to get them into unity, something wrong happened, I tried a lot of methods. Like using script to attach, using Position constrains and rotation constrain, but still can't fix this issue. I even tried IK, not working.as well.

In my case, I play the running animation in the arm and the gun was not playing animations.

[This video shows my problem](https://youtu.be/9NA0uNwgCwo?si=WaJjPW4akNNt-mKD).

And here is a video of [what it looks like in Blender](https://youtu.be/oA2RqO2fCh8?si=wCbcloWc7GUHT2Qf).

And here is how I put models in Unity:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nvm I managed to solve this by myself, in the import setting, the animations are compressed by default for some reasion, I have to disable it to solve this.

Comment: This answer would be even better if it explained the steps to take to disable compression, so future readers struggling with similar problems can learn from your example.